# Virtual Gl host and display from same pc?

Tags: opengl, steam, xvfb, display-server

I'm trying to set up a virtual gl client to connect with an Xvfb display from within the same pc. I start up the client and then try to connect to it from the other display and it says the connection is refused. I can paste the specific error when I get access to my pc again but I don't see a point since it doesn't specify anything more than the server it tried to connect to.

To reproduce this is run xvfb on display :2, set `DISPLAY=:2` and run the following:

```
vglclient -d :0 & vglconnect -d :2 user@pc-name
```

It sets up a server on port 4242 and then refuses the connection from the display side.

I tested vglrun and it works just fine give or take some color issues (probably an Xvfb issue) so I know xvfb isn't to blame nor can I see why it would be a problem. I just need to extend that environment to the whole xvfb display.

Added (possibly unnecessary?) context in case anyone needs more info:
I'm trying to set a personal cloud gaming server from my daily driver pc for when I'm not using it. I've opted to run Xvfb with VirtualGL and stream in through Sunshine. The first and last layers work, but I need a way for virtual gl to run display wide instead of just for a single program. Steam doesn't launch any games when it's started with vglrun.